# Graphs: traverse every edge in undirected graph with shortest path

Tags: python, graph

I have n roads and m cities. Each road has its own length. I need to visit all roads and find the shortest path for that.
A graph is connected. I can start from any city.

How can i do this? I can use dfs or bfs to traverse the graph. But it’s not only about traversing all edges but finding the shortest path.

I can find shortest paths from the source node to all other nodes, but it doesn’t guarantee traversal of all edges.

Comment: This is the super classic salesman problem. If you spent just 2 minutes searching for it, you'd have found dozens of pages about it.

Comment: @Julien I am not sure. I don't need to return to the origin city and visit each city just once.